# What is the difference between declaring a string with const string and string const

Tags: c++

I'm browsing some code in the net, and I saw this two declaration,

```
const std::string strFoo = "MyFoo";
```

and

```
std::string const strBar = "MyBar";
```

I'm confused about the different placement of const keyword. What exactly its purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing. The language purposely allows initial const for the base type to be either before or after the type, but only for that specific decl form. `const char *` and `char const *` are another such example. The purpose is to declare the immutable state of the aforementioned variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it makes *no difference*.

For more complicated declarations it may make a big difference.

You could say that `const` applies to what is to the left and if there's nothing there, it applies to what is to the right.

For example using `const` qualifier on a pointer to int:

```
const int* ptr1;        // (1.) pointer to const int
int const * ptr2;       // (2.) same as 1.
int* const ptr3;        // (3.) const pointer to int
const int* const ptr4;  // (4.) const pointer to const int
int const * const ptr4; // (5.) same as 4.
```

For more info on how to read complicated type declarations se this: [C Right-Left Rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html)

Comment: -1 for The Clockwise/Spiral Rule. This rule breaks the order of precedence so it can't even parse declarations like `int a[4][5]`. Also it is overcomplicated. Use Right-Left rule instead: http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html, which simly follows the order of precedence without wrong assumption about "clockwise direction".

Comment: @kotlomoy If you parse symbols like `[][]` in a single pass in the spiral, it works. But looking at the link you provided, the right-left rule indeed seems more intuitive (too bad though it doesn't mention on how to handle const qualifiers). I've updated my answer.

Comment: +1 for edition. `const` qualifiers obey order of precedence, so Right-Left Rule  works well. For example, `int const * const ptr4;` - parsing from `ptr4` to the left we get "const pointer to const int". There is one notable ugly exception - for some reason it is allowed to wright `const` to the left of type like here: `const int* ptr1;`. I really don't like this because it breaks order of precedence and consequently Right-Left Rule.